# Spring Boot записывает данные не в ту колонку в БД(сам создает)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Вот код POJO класса,объект которого я хочу записать в БД.

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "testscheduletable")
public class TestScheduleTable implements Comparable<TestScheduleTable> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "facultyName")
    private String facultyName;
    @NotNull
    private String specialtyName;
    @NotNull
    private String groupName;
    @NotNull
    private String subjectName;
    @NotNull
    private String teacherName;
    @NotNull
    private String classroomName;
    @NotNull
    private String lessonType;
    @NotNull
    private String time;
    @NotNull
    private String date;

    public TestScheduleTable() {
    }
//дальше геттеры сеттеры+ конструктор
```

филд `facultyName` должен записываться в колонку `facultyName`, но Spring Boot создает колонку `faculty_name` и туда записывает, как можно это исправить, может быть как то вручную пометить в XML конфигурации?
вот еще часть контроллера которая записывает

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public String putMyData(TestScheduleTable schedule) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    testService.save(schedule);
    return returnUrl("admin",
            schedule.getFacultyName(),
            schedule.getSpecialtyName(),
            schedule.getGroupName(),
            schedule.getDate());
}
```

Comment: А для остальных колонок все работает как ожидается? Колонки создаются в camelCase?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать

```
@Column(name = "`facultyName`")
```

Хотя, это зависит от версии hibernate, операционной системы (файловой системы), диалекту, стратегии наименований переменных, где учитывается или игнорируется регистр.

Comment: пробовал, выдает ошибку